# How to put CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER page in iframe?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, curl, user-agent

I have to put this page: http://www.tvindiretta.com/m/ in a iframe. This page is cURL powered. He is it's content. When I try to put this url: http://www.tvindiretta.com/m/index.php in an iframe (with  tag) the browser redirects to the iframe url. How can I keep this page inside the iframe. I have to change the user user agent. the I'm a complete noob in cURL but help me please. He is the /m/index.php page source code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.tvindiretta.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 2_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/525.18.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.1.1 Mobile/5H11 Safari/525.20'));

curl_exec($ch);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

print $result;
curl_close($ch);
?> $
```

Comment: cURL has **nothing** to do with iframes.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Prevent frame-busting?

Comment: I just want to put this page: http://www.tvindiretta.com/m into an iframe

Comment: You would have to modify the page, removing the JavaScript that does the frame busting. This is not a legitimate way to use content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an user-agent redirection on this web page since

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['get'])){

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.tvindiretta.com/m");
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    print $result;

}
else{
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="test.php?get" style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px; width:400px; height:400px;"/>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Seems to screw the page, but provide me the mobile content anyway.

So I guess the real problem here is the javascript code inside that page:

In html5 you have a new [iframe attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) "sandbox" which allows you to restrict the iframe's content behaviour .
Unfortunately this seems to be supported only by Chrome and Safari.

One idea here could be to try to scrape the content of the web page (with [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.domdocument.php) in PHP for instance), keep only the content in which you are interested, and try to reproduce their style. It may be easier to say than to do, but I can't see a cleaner way to do so.

Since it seems you are interested in getting a TV program, you could check for a dedicated xml scaper [XMLtv](http://wiki.xmltv.org/index.php/Main_Page).